# Firebase, angular example, difference between incoming and outcoming bytes; total bytes transferred

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a firebase and there I have a "Wire up a Backend" example from angularjs.org.

There are free string data: `name`, `description`, `url`.

I wrote 3 times `name`,`description`,`url` by that sample example.

I noticed big difference between incoming and outcoming data:

1. incoming about 100 bytes
2. outcoming about 224 bytes

Why? I send / read the same data...

Secondly: Do the "total bytes transferred" refer to incoming data or outcoming data or sum of both? I want to laungh a service: logged users will be putting numbers, and I want to sum all the numbers and then put the information (about the sum) on the web. How can I optimize bandwidth and total bytes transferred?

Comment: Are you sure about bytes per second? Aren't these kB or MB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the angularFire service sends the whole object every time which account for the outgoing bandwidth. This will be fixed in subsequent versions, (follow [this issue on Github](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/25)) in the mean time, you can use the angularFireCollection service which only writes models that changed to save on outgoing bandwidth.

Total bytes transferred refers to the sum of outgoing and incoming bandwidth as seen by the Firebase servers.